# How is the service provider in AddScoped/Transient/Singleton in an IServiceCollection created? Can't resolve a service that has previously been added

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm adding services to an `IServiceCollection`. I want to use a service that I have already added to the collection in a factory method for another service.
Using the AddScoped (presumably it's the same for `AddTransient` and `AddSingleton`, but I'm using Scoped) method to provide a `Func<IServiceProvider, IMyService>` as an argument, the `IServiceProvider` can't resolve a service that has already been added to the `IServiceCollection`.

As mentioned, I initially tried to use an `implementationFactory` method using the `IServiceProvider` that is automatically provided into that method. This `IServiceProvider` threw an exception when trying to resolve a service that I had already registered higher in the code.

After searching around for a while I discovered an extension method on `IServiceCollection` - `BuildServiceProvider()`. Using the service provider produced by this method allows me to successfully resolve the service. So what makes this different to the `IServiceProvider` passed in to the implementation factory method?

```cs
// The below throws an exception when attempting to resolve ISomeGeneric<SomeType>.
// Note that it successfully resolves ISomeInterface
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ISomeInterface, SomeImplementation>();
    services.AddScoped(typeof(ISomeGeneric<>), typeof(SomeGeneric<>));

    services.AddScoped<IThingToResolve>(serviceProvider => new ThingToResolve(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISomeInterface>(), serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISomeGeneric<SomeType>>());
}

// Below is the solution I ended up implementing
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ISomeInterface, SomeImplementation>();
    services.AddScoped(typeof(ISomeGeneric<>), typeof(SomeGeneric<>));

    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    services.AddScoped<IThingToResolve>(spThatIsNotUsed => new ThingToResolve(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISomeInterface>(), serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISomeGeneric<SomeType>>()));
}
```

The error that is thrown is `` Cannot resolve scoped service 'ISomeGeneric`1[SomeType]' from root provider. ``

As I mentioned above, even when using this method, the `ISomeInterface` service is resolved, so I can't understand why all of my services are not included in this service provider

Comment: Why do you use `services.AddScoped<ISomeInterface, ISomeImplementation>();` instead of `services.AddScoped<ISomeInterface, SomeImplementation>();` where `SomeImplementation` implements `ISomeInterface`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, just a mistake in the question. Edited now

Comment: `services.AddScoped(typeof(ISomeGeneric<>), typeof(SomeGeneric<>);`  it looks like one bracket is missing at the end.